# how to use javascript to invoke the value of an html special data attribute and pass to php array in yii 1.1.14?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, yii

I have an anchor link where the data-url has a value of a yii create url like this

```
<a href="#" id="download-button" data-url="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('controllerName/actionName',array('var1'=>'var1_value', 'var2' => 'var2_value', 'var3' => '?')); ?>" data-chosen-type="">CLICK ME</a>
```

so the situation is like this, you see the data-chosen-type="" attribute?, the value is actually being set by a javascript. Now what I want to happen is, grab the value of data-chosen-type attribute and place it to 'var3' value, within the array inside that createUrl thing. So the output should be like this

```
 <a href="#" id="download-button" data-url="<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('controllerName/actionName',array('var1'=>'var1_value', 'var2' => 'var2_value', 'var3' => 'value of data-chosen-type')); ?>" data-chosen-type="">CLICK ME</a>
```

is that possible to do?
I tried doing this

```
'var3' => "js:$('#download-button').attr('data-chosen-type')"
```

it didn't work, but in a view file especially in CGridView, putting javascript in a value of a key pair does work...how come in createUrl I wasn't able to do the same thing? am I doing it wrongly?

Comment: No, that is of course not possible, because PHP is long done before anything JavaScripty happens on the client.

Comment: any idea to solve my problem?. I know a dirty way, but it's dirty. So I better ask experts in stackoverlfow

Comment: AJAX request to the server, so that you can call the createUrl method there with the correct parameters ...

Comment: I used ajax request instead....but it's not what I wanted to happen. but it worked anyway. thanks..put your answer in a separate box so that I can accept as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible, because PHP is long done before anything JavaScripty happens on the client.

If you can not determine the value on the server-side at all - then make an AJAX request to the server, so that you can call the createUrl method there with the correct parameters, and then set the link data-url attribute with the returned URL.